# Form submit isn't being triggered in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, form-submit

I'm trying to get a submit event to fire but I'm not having any luck.

Here is the jquery call that doesn't work.

```
$(document).on("submit", '#studentSubmit', function(event) {//do something here});
```

this call here works fine

```
$("#studentSubmit").submit(function (event) {
```

but I need to have a call like the one above because I will be replacing this form dynamically with ajax calls.

and here is my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveStudent", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new {@id="studentSubmit", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{@*my form here*@}
```

Comment: why `@id`, you can directly given `id="studentSubmit"` since `id`  isn't a reserved keyword.

Comment: Do the replacement forms also have `id="studentSubmit"`? Any reason why not just `$(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {`?

Comment: because I'm replacing the html with another form so I need to be able to make a distinction between the two if I submit. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: if I do on('submit', 'form', function() { is there a way to tell which form has been submitted?

Comment: I'm trying .on('submit', 'form', function() { but I can't seem to get it to trigger, any reasons why?